# Association undefined method `id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello guys this error is giving me a headache for days and I seriously don't know what's happening. So, I have 2 models: `User` and `Composition`. Compositions have a `belongs_to :user` and the user have `has_many :compositions` and one controller which is giving an error when I try to get de user id from the composition's owner(user).

**Error**

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

<%= link_to profile_path(compos.user.id), class: 'ui-btn btn-small' do %>
  <span class="icon-export"></span>visitar perfil</a>
<% end %>
```

**Composition**

```
class Composition < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true, :length => {maximum: 120}
  validates :description, presence: true

  has_attached_file :thumbnail
  validates_attachment_content_type :thumbnail, content_type: /\Aimage/
  validates_attachment_file_name :thumbnail, matches: [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :thumbnail
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :compositions

  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :omniauthable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  # Validações
  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar

  validates_format_of :username, :with => /[\w]+/
  validates_length_of :username, :in => (5..32)
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  #Previne que o avatar tenha um tamanho maior de 2MB
  private
  def avatar_size_validation
    errors[:avatar] << "should be less than 2MB" if avatar.size > 2.megabytes
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @compositions = Composition.all.order('created_at desc').limit(4)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the composition has the user too..kindly verify from the rails console...

Comment: Yap.. you're right, for some reason it didnt create a composition with the current user id

Comment: I guess you are using a iterator in that view to iterate all @compositions by `each`. So verify that all the `compositions` have a user. Even if a single composition missing an user, that would give this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set if condition to check if `compos.user` is present.

```
<% if compos.user %>
```

But, Seems like it's data inconsistency as I think you are working on development environment

You need to make sure for each `composition` user_id must exist.

```
class Composition < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

This way you will never have compos with `user_id = nil`

Comment: Ohh ok,  thanks, im still trying to figure out this framework(since im a newbie in rais) xD